# Expected :Mock for User, hashCode: 1835841364 Actual :null

Tags: testing, mockito

I wrote a mock test for my UserService class and don't understand why the test is showing as orange for the create method. I'm trying to figure out if it's due to a misspelled method or a misspelled test. Here is my Order class.

```
/**
 * A class that represents an order and contains the selected products and the customer.
 */

@Entity
@Table(name = "orders", schema = "public")
public class Order {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    //@JoinColumn
    private Product product;

    @ManyToMany
    private List<Product> products;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    //Multiple orders can belong to one customer. This means that a customer can place several orders.
    private User user;


    public Order() {
        //Default constructor
    }

    public Order(User user, Product product) {
        this.user = user;
        this.product = product;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Product getProduct() {
        return product;
    }

    public void setProduct(Product product) {
        this.product = product;
    }

    public List<Product> getProducts() {
        return products;
    }
    public void setProducts(List<Product> products) {
        this.products = products;
    }
    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }
}
```

And my OrderService class:

```
/**
 * A class that implements the order process and includes functions to create orders, display the order history of a customer and confirm the order.
 */
@Service
public class OrderService {
    @Autowired
    OrderRepository or;

    public void save(Order order) {
        or.save(order);
    }
    public List<Order> listAll(){
        return (List<Order>) or.findAll();
    }

    public Order create(User user, Product product) {
        Order newOrder = new Order();
        newOrder.setUser(user);
        newOrder.setProduct(product);
        return or.save(newOrder);
    }

    public void delete(Long id) {
        Optional<Order> existingOrder= or.findById(id);
        if(existingOrder.isPresent()){
            or.deleteById(id);
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Order with ID " + id + " not found.");
        }
    }
}
```

Meine Klasse OrderRepository:

```
@Repository
    public interface OrderRepository extends CrudRepository<Order, Long> {
        long countById(Long id); }
```

And here is the mock test that is displaying as orange:

```
public class OrderServiceTest {

    @InjectMocks
    private OrderService orderService;
    @InjectMocks
    private ProductService productService;

    @Mock
    private OrderRepository orderRepository;
    @Mock
    private ProductRepository productRepository;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void testCreateOrder() {
        MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this);

        Product product = new Product();
        product.setProductName("productName_0");
        product.setProductSalePrice(1290.78);

        User mockUser = Mockito.mock(User.class); // Create a mock User object

        Order mockOrder = new Order();

        when(orderRepository.save(any(Order.class))).thenReturn(mockOrder);

        Order createdOrder = orderService.create(mockUser, product);

        assertNotNull(createdOrder);
        assertEquals(mockUser, createdOrder.getUser());
        assertEquals(product, createdOrder.getProduct());

        verify(orderRepository, times(1)).save(any(Order.class));
    }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jEzW1.jpg)I have already tried making changes in the test. Because in the databases, it's correctly labeled as 'User,' more specifically 'UserId,' so that's even more confusing for me.

Answer (score 0):

Let's break it down:

```
Order mockOrder = new Order(); // this is not a Mockito mock

when(orderRepository.save(any(Order.class))).thenReturn(mockOrder);

Order createdOrder = orderService.create(mockUser, product);

// at this point: createdOrder == mockOrder (same reference)
```

Your `Order` class with parameterless constructor (`new Order()`):

```
public class Order {
    private Long id;
    private Product product;
    private List<Product> products;

    private User user;

    public Order() {
        // Parameterless constructor: all fields default-initialized
    }

    // ...
}
```

And then your assertion:

```
assertEquals(mockUser, createdOrder.getUser());
```

Remember: `createdOrder == mockOrder` and `mockOrder` is only a default-initialized instance of your class, so its `user` field is still `null`.

If you require your test doubles to return particular values, you have to set them up accordingly. But then I would be wondering what your test is testing. You could completely mess up the implementation of your service, pass the wrong Order instance to your repo, etc. and your test would still succeed because the only line that's relevant is `return or.save(newOrder)` and that method is stubbed as `when(orderRepository.save(any(Order.class))).thenReturn(mockOrder)`, meaning it will return the same `mockOrder` instance, for *any* input except `null`.

Your test is not testing anything useful. It is only testing that Mockito can stub the return values of interface calls.

---

A more meaningful test could be:

```
@Test
public void testCreateOrder() {
    Product product = new Product();
    product.setProductName("productName_0");
    product.setProductSalePrice(1290.78);

    User mockUser = Mockito.mock();

    orderService.create(mockUser, product);

    final ArgumentCaptor<Order> captor
            = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Order.class);
    verify(orderRepository).save(captor.capture());

    final Order savedOrder = captor.getValue();
    assertEquals(mockUser, order.getUser());
    assertEquals(product, order.getProduct());
}
```

It verifies that `repository.save` has been called with an order that has the user and product set correctly. But if you are testing database interactions, I would recommend writing an integration test which actually persists your entity.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback and the detailed explanation of the test scenario. I understand the points. I actually wanted to test whether my create method for Order is implemented correctly. I am new and still learning. Thank you for the advice. Now, the topic of mocking has become somewhat clearer to me. I would then adjust my test something like this:

Comment: @user22566443 I have extended my answer to show a test that's more meaningful in my opinion.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help and correction! I still feel unsure about mock testing, but I will learn. That's exactly what I wanted.